# Phonegap : Button click listening is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am developing an Android app in Phonegap. I have 3 page , by using "**Button click**" the page is going to another page. My issues is when I click the button response is very slow, it took 1 to 2 sec to go to the next page.

Here am using **div** transition to show each page "homePage" and "imgSelectPage" are class name for **div**.

```
 $('.play a').click( function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.homePage').hide();
    $('.imgSelectPage').show();
});
```

Is there any method to improve the speed to change one page to another page by clicking the button

Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace 2 jQuery lines with alert("test"); You need to check if jQuery hide() / show() takes long time in this case.

Comment: @xiaowu am using div transition to show each page "homePage" and "imgSelectPage" are class name for div.is there any other method other than using jQuery

Comment: Do you use FastClick for mobile app. In mobile, event click will be wait 300ms to fire.

Comment: @ Hanh Le yes , i used fastclick, but no improvement

Answer (score 0):

If you use the selectors more then once you could set a variable. This is more effective because jQuery only searches the element once.

And use the minified version of jquery and not a debug version.

If this did not help you should inspect how the methods .hide() and .show() behave just like @xiaowu said

Comment: yes am using minified version of jquery . As xiaowu  said am agree with his point , because of jQuery it look like slow tarncition. But is there any other method for transition of div class other than using jQuery

Comment: Yes, you can use angularJS. And if you want to build an application in material design I recommend [AngularMaterial](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/). We developed a cordova application quiet fast with the help of these libraries.